# How could I create multiple private sites within one Drupal site?

Tags: users

Can I create a Drupal site, where a user, let's call her Jane, can create an account and publish some content, like a few articles. Then create accounts for her friends who can login and view all the nodes she has created, and which they create. At the same time, Paul creates an account, creates some nodes, and invites his friends etc. However, Paul and his friends cannot see Jane's nodes or users - and vice versa. It feels to Jane and Paul that they have there own separate website.

What are the key Drupal concepts or methods for creating a site like this? Thanks.

Comment: Both of these are interesting suggestions. I'd never heard of either. I guess I'll investigate OG first and if it doesn't do everything I need, look into multi-sites. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This seems like a *perfect* use case for [Organic Groups](http://drupal.org/project/og).

> Enable users to create and manage their own 'groups'. Each group can
>   have subscribers, and maintains a group home page where subscribers
>   communicate amongst themselves.

I'm not going to go in depth with setup or anything, as OG is a **beast** of a module, but the benefits are immense, and should allow you to do exactly what you need. It's the same module that provides the [groups.drupal.org](http://groups.drupal.org/frontpage) functionality :)

A quick Google search will provide a wealth or information, as will a browse of the [organic-groups](/questions/tagged/organic-groups) tag.

Also check these out for a brief overview of OG:

- [Organic Groups for Drupal 7 (Lullabot)](http://www.lullabot.com/blog/articles/organic-groups-drupal-7)
- [An Introduction to Organic Groups with Drupal 7 (YouTube/Lullabot/Drupalize.me)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MWEyG8iL2Vc)

Answer (score 0):

> However, Paul and his friends cannot see Jane's nodes or users - and vice versa. It feels to Jane and Paul that they have there own separate website.

Organic Groups (as suggested by Chapabu) may well be the solution you're after, but it is (IMHO) not a module that is easy to set up or manage.

As an alternative, in particular if you want a clear and total separation between Paul's and Jane's "sites" you can achieve this by means of a so-called multi-site.  A multi-site allows you to share a single Drupal installation (including core, contributed modules, and themes) among several sites, where each site has its own database, content, and users.

The canonical documentation for setting up a multi-site can be found at [Drupal.org: Multisite](http://drupal.org/documentation/install/multi-site).

In addition to the official documentation, you may want to read my tutorial about setting up a multi-site [here](http://heim.ifi.uio.no/gisle/staging2/drupalprimer/drupal/drupal_install.html#multi). I hope the instructions are clear enough to follow.

Comment: The functionality asked for is waaaaay below the need for a multisite install. A multisite method would involve each user having to have a dev/sysadmin set up their own site instance.

Comment: I don't think the answer is *wrong*, I just think a multisite approach would be like using a sledgehammer to squash a spider (note - in the UK we have small spiders ;-)).

Comment: It is relatively heavy handed for what the OP wants.  "user A creates an account and logs in, creates private content, user b creates an account and logs in, creates private content".

The main reason I think that the multi site approach is *possibly* incorrect in this use case is because it still requires dev/sysadmin action for every individual "site".  An OG can be created/maintained directly by an end user with zero dev/sysadmin input.

Comment: Just to clarify my standing as well:  I am not saying you are *wrong* as that would be rude as this is a "horses for courses" question really, I'm just politely disagreeing :-)

Comment: @Gisle Hannemyr - can you elaborate on this point in your tutorial: Sub-directory 7. Create a symbolic link in the drupal root directory making a sandbox sub-directory that (via a symbolic link) points to the Drupal root directory (ln -s . sandbox). Where does this line of code go? Thanks.